# How to make faster large data (5,000,000) in Django with Datatables No django-datatables-view No Rest Framework

Tags: django, datatables

I want to take large data (examples 5 000,000) with datatables in Django .But Proccessing is slowly (Page Load is 12 seconds).Users login to webpage. Then Click to Test .html. Backend procces run to test_json in Views. Views call taking db data with to_dict_json.  On Models.py. This method in Views return Json response objects.
How to make faster large data in Django with datatables

Models.py

```
class SysTest(models.Model):

class Meta:
    db_table = 'sysTest'

id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
Tip = models.ForeignKey(SysRefTip, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
Kod = models.CharField(_("Kod"), max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
Aciklama1 = models.CharField(_("Açıklama 1"), max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
Aciklama2 = models.CharField(_("Açıklama 2"), max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
GrupKod = models.CharField(_("Grup Kodu"), max_length=20,blank=True, null=True)
SayKod = models.FloatField(_("Sayısal Değer"),blank=True, null=True)

def to_dict_json(self):

    return{
        'Id':self.id,
        'Kod':self.Kod,
        'Aciklama1':self.Aciklama1,
        'Aciklama2':self.Aciklama2,
        'GrupKod':self.GrupKod,
        'SayKod':self.SayKod,
    }
```

View.py

```
def test_json(request):
    persons  = SysTest.objects.all()
    data = [person.to_dict_json() for person in persons ]
    response = {'data': data}
   return JsonResponse(response,safe=False,content_type="application/json")
```

Urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from Referans.Views import testView
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
app_name ="Test"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', testView.test_listele , name="test"),
    path('test/json/', testView.test_json, name='test_json'),

]
```

test.html

```
            <div class="card-body">

                <table id="myTable2" class="table datatable-responsive-control-right">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Kod</th>
                        <th>Açıklama1</th>
                        <th>Açıklama2</th>
                        <th>SayKod</th>
                        <th>GrupKod</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>





                </div>

            {% block js%}
            <script>

            $(document).ready( function () {
            var t0 = performance.now();
            degerleriGetir('test/json')
            var t1 = performance.now();

            });

            function degerleriGetir(data){

                table =$('#myTable2').DataTable({
                        Serverside:true,
                        Processing: true,
                        orderClasses: false,
                        bSortClasses:false,
                        bDeferRender: true,
                        scrollCollapse: true,
                        scrollY: 500,
                        stateSave: true,
                        scroller: {
                            loadingIndicator: true
                        },            
                        ajax:{
                        url:('test/json'),
                        processing:true,
                        },
                        destroy:true,
                        columns: [
                        {'data': 'Id'},
                        {'data': 'Kod'},
                        {'data': 'Aciklama1'},
                        {'data': 'Aciklama2'},
                        {'data': 'GrupKod'},
                        {'data': 'SayKod'}  
                        ]
                    });
            };

            </script>

            {% endblock js  %}
```

Comment: you must use paginator... you can't show such big data at same time.

Comment: Hi Lu, I don't want show big data at same time. I don know how to use paginator in datatables.

Comment: Do you want asynchronous loading?

Comment: Lue , Can you give a example asynchronous loading in django

Answer (score 0):

Asyncronous loading is made with ajax request, for example. The javascript controls which pages the user wants to see, making a request to django "view_url+?page=X". Then, get the info (usually in json) and loads the content into html. I never used DataTable, so i can't tell you exactly what you have to do. What I am telling you is what you can do to achieve this asynchronous loading. Other option is paginating normally, loading the page each time for each page (so much easier to implement by hand). Take a look to django ListView model to make your implementation easier and faster!

Good luck!

Comment: Hello Lue,     I know this information But. I don't know how to make effective faster data in Django with datatables. Solution contain datatables. Because Using template contain datatables . I just want to fster takin data . Thank you for answer.

Comment: Your view is slow because you are trying to load so much elements into html, and render the view in a big context data. You must be sure that the context sent is not that big. With pagination you solve this problem. Then you choose how to make it work (async/sync).